# Workaround for Showing AAD Login Screen for site hosted in IFrame

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We are hosting our site in IFrame and user gets authenticate through AAD login. Currently AAD Login page cannot be shown inside IFrame. If the user already authenticated through AAD, they can access page. Incase, If the user is not authenticated, Site redirects to AAD LoginPage. which doesn't get rendered.is there any workaround to show AAD Login page in popup and get authenticated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the typical AAD OAuth code flow from Azure you would do the Auth in the outer real page surrounding the IFrame.  The user will have to login in once typically.

The concept is that you have to do a **full redirect** to the Auth pages at MS.  Not in an IFrame or as a background call or popup but a complete current session redirect to something like mysite.onmicrosft.com/authorize  .  One of the **critical parameters** you pass when you send them off to MS is the redirectURL.  That brings them Back to your site after login on Azure.

This page has an interesting graphic.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code

Even If You somehow had the IFrame working I would not rely on that as policies or future lockdowns of the process will invalidate your IFrame method easily.  (google will not allow the IFrame to be used.)

An interesting alternative is to make your user login before they go to your IFrame.

Comment: Thanks SQL Surfer